# Is it safe to drill into the side of a fridge?

Tags: kegerator

I want to transform a compressor wine fridge into a kegerator. I wanted to know where it would be safe to drill holes, either in the side or the top? There is no freezer section, and the back of the fridge is a snake of coils. Does this tell me anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every fridge is different, so you cannot tell just by what fridge it is.

You can get an idea as to where the coolant lines are by using a paste made from mixing some cornflour with alcohol and coating the sides when the fridge is off. Then start the fridge and watch where the paste starts to dry.

Even once you think it's safe, it is best to slowly dig out the insulation with a screwdriver, so that it is obvious if you hit a coolant line, rather than just drilling straight through.

Comment: How do I make said paste?

Comment: Mix some cornflour with alcohol (or high alcohol spirit).

Comment: @ tristan2468: Interesting idea, but I would have thought the paste would dry more slowly over the cold lines. Or have I misunderstood your instructions? If I had corn flour and PGA on hand (I assume corn meal won't do, and I can't buy PGA in Canada) I'd try it myself. Never know when I'll get the urge to drill into a fridge ;-).

Answer (score 2):

You can also try Googling the specific model of refrigerator to see if anyone else has tried drilling into it.  Occasionally the service manual is available, too, which might have a coolant routing diagram that will help.